# JPA one-to-many relationship not working properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, debugging, jpa

I have an issue with my relationship between Membre and Sortie but I can't figure out what I did wrong. Everytime I run my test it triggers an exception.

Can someone help me with this please ?

**Membre.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Membre")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor

public class Membre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idMembre ;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String nomMembre ;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String prenomMembre ;
    
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private String adresseElectronique ; 
    
    //Il est plus sure d'utiliser un char[] plutot qu'un String pour un mot de passe 
    @Basic(optional = false)
    private char[] motDePasse ;
    
    @Version
    private long versionMembre = 0 ;
    
    public Membre(String nom, String prenom, String email, char[] mdp, Set<Sortie> sorties){
        this(0, nom, prenom, email, mdp, 0, sorties);
    }
    
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            mappedBy = "createurSortie",
            cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    @ToString.Exclude
    @OrderBy("idSortie asc")
    private Set<Sortie> sortiesMembre ;
    
    public void addSortie(Sortie s) {
        if (sortiesMembre == null) {
            sortiesMembre = new HashSet<>();
        }
        sortiesMembre.add(s);
        s.setCreateurSortie(this);
    }
    
    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeUpdate() {
        System.err.println("PreUpdate␣of␣" + this);
    }
    @PostUpdate
    public void afterUpdate() {
        System.err.println("PostUpdate␣of␣" + this);
    }
}
```

**Sortie.java**

```
@Entity(name = "Sortie")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedQuery(
        name="findSortiesByCriteria",
        query="SELECT s FROM Sortie s WHERE s.descriptionSortie LIKE :pattern"
)
public class Sortie implements Serializable {
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long idSortie ;
    
    @Basic
    private String nomSortie ;
    
    @Basic
    private String descriptionSortie ;
    
    @Basic
    private URL siteWebSortie ;
    
    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateSortie ;
    
    @Version
    private long versionSortie = 0 ;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "idMembre")
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Membre createurSortie;
    
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @ToString.Exclude
    private Categorie categorie ;
    
    public Sortie(String nomSortie, String descriptionSortie, URL siteWebSortie, Date dateSortie,Membre createurSortie,Categorie categorie) {
        this(0, nomSortie, descriptionSortie, siteWebSortie, dateSortie, 0, createurSortie, categorie);
    }
    
    @PreUpdate
    public void beforeUpdate() {
    System.err.println("PreUpdate␣of␣" + this);
    }
    @PostUpdate
    public void afterUpdate() {
    System.err.println("PostUpdate␣of␣" + this);
    }

}
```

**My test**

```
    @Test
    public void testGetMembreAndSorties() {
        var membre = new Membre("Katon","Den","dean.keaon@jk.com",new char[] {'j', 'j'},null);
        
        dao.addMember(membre);

        var sortie1 = new Sortie("Sortie à la montagne", "Une sortie dans la montagne.", null, null, null, null);
        
        dao.addSortie(sortie1);
        
        membre.addSortie(sortie1);
        
        Membre foundMember = dao.findMember(membre.getIdMembre());
        assertEquals(1,foundMember.getSortiesMembre().size());

        dao.removeMember(foundMember.getIdMembre());
        dao.removeSortie(sortie1.getIdSortie());
    }
```

**The exception**
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <1> but was: <0>

Which means that the Sortie that I added to the member wasn't stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Delete @Data and use @Getter and @Setter if necessary.

  - StackOverFlow infinite reference problem occurs due to @EqualsAndHashCode in two-way association.
- After deleting @Data and replacing it with @Getter and @Setter, I wrote the following test.

  - I passed the test and checked the logs as expected.

```java
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleTest {

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Test
    void testGetMembreAndSorties() {
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
        tx.begin();
        var membre = new Membre("Katon", "Den", "dean.keaon@jk.com", new char[]{'j', 'j'}, null);
        em.persist(membre);

        var sortie1 = new Sortie("Sortie à la montagne", "Une sortie dans la montagne.", null, null, null);
        em.persist(sortie1);

        membre.addSortie(sortie1);

        Membre foundMember = em.find(Membre.class, membre.getIdMembre());
        tx.commit();
        assertEquals(1, foundMember.getSortiesMembre().size());
    }
}
```

#### Log

```
Hibernate: select next value for membre_seq
Hibernate: select next value for sortie_seq
PreUpdate␣of␣com.example.demo.domain.Membre@5b3f0552
PreUpdate␣of␣com.example.demo.domain.Sortie@708f4d81
Hibernate: insert into membre (adresse_electronique,mot_de_passe,nom_membre,prenom_membre,version_membre,id_membre) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
Hibernate: insert into sortie (id_membre,date_sortie,description_sortie,nom_sortie,site_web_sortie,version_sortie,id_sortie) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
PostUpdate␣of␣com.example.demo.domain.Membre@5b3f0552
Hibernate: update sortie set id_membre=?,date_sortie=?,description_sortie=?,nom_sortie=?,site_web_sortie=?,version_sortie=? where id_sortie=? and version_sortie=?
PostUpdate␣of␣com.example.demo.domain.Sortie@708f4d81
```

It is expected that something in the DAO of your code is causing a problem.

I hope it will be of help. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try that and I'll tell you if it works !

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't stored because you are calling `membre.addSortie` after saving entities in dao.

Also, I don't recommend you to use `@Data` for your entities, it may cause unexpected behavior (more details here https://jpa-buddy.com/blog/lombok-and-jpa-what-may-go-wrong/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer I will try that and I'll tell you if it works !